# Bootstrap 4 CSS is not applied

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and my css file somehow doesn't work.

I want to give space for this navigation bar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-bottom">
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I added this code:

```
.navbar-nav>li{margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px;}
```

It **WORKS** but only when i put the code on the meta tag of index file, but **not working** when i put the code on bootstrap.min.css even though I put the CSS file on the right directory.

```
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

**How can this happen?**

How come the class .fixed-bottom affects my navigation code without linking the CSS file?  .fixed-bottom class is on bootstrap.css which lines is not exist on the meta tag, there's only bootstrap.min.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and it works ok, you can create a second CSS file to contain your custom rules (maybe custom.css), i think it's not a good pratice to insert custom code inside plugin CSS.

> How come the class .fixed-bottom have an effect on my navigation code eventough there's no code linking for the css file (.fixed-bottom class is on bootstrap.css which lines is not exist on the meta tag, there's only bootstrap.min)

This is because there is no difference between bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css, the CSS rules inside the files are the same, only the "min" one is compressed for performance.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.navbar-nav>li{margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px;}
</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-bottom">
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never edit bootstrap.min.css.  Otherwise, when a new version comes out, you have to recreate whatever changes you made.  Write your own CSS *separately* and include it *after* bootstrap's so that anything you write will override Bootstrap (that's the "Cascade" in Cascading Style Sheets).

Also consider using the Content Delivery Network ([Look for "Bootstrap CDN" here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/)) so that if someone ever visited another site that uses Bootstrap, the won't have to download it again to use your site.